# Why does bash test.sh work but not ./test.sh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Running `bash test.sh` works. But running `./test.sh` doesn't work. Why is this?

$PATH

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ echo $PATH
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/bin
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Test
```

Console output:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ ls
Applications    Downloads   Movies      Public
Desktop     Dropbox     Music       code
Documents   Library     Pictures    test.sh
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ sudo !!
sudo ./test.sh
Password:
sudo: ./test.sh: command not found
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ bash test.sh
Test
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$
```

File permissions:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ stat test.sh
16777220 1752325 -rw-r--r-- 1 adamzerner staff 0 22 "May 20 20:23:07 2016" "May 20 20:04:40 2016" "May 20 20:04:40 2016" "May 20 20:03:40 2016" 4096 8 0 test.sh
```

Comment: Does `test.sh` have execute permissions? Edit your post to include the output of `stat test.sh`

Comment: @muru I don't know. a) How can I figure that out? b) Why would that lead to `bash` working but `./` not working? c) Wouldn't `sudo` fix that problem?

Comment: a) `stat test.sh` look for something like `rwxr-xr-x`, in particular, the `x`. b) `bash` has execute permissions, and you're running `bash` there, not the script directly, c) no.

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the script execute permission:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Executing a file as a program requires execute permission. When you use `bash test.sh`, it's not being executed as a program, it's just an input file to the `bash` program, and that program just needs to be able to read it (just like `cat test.sh` only needs to be able to read it).